# Scrape specific <td> in HTML table

Tags: php, html, html-table, simple-html-dom, scrape

I am trying to scrape a table using PHP, the thing is that I've managed to scrape it, but I get *everything* on the webpage's table. I am unsure how I specify which TD's and/or TR's I want to scrape.

Here's the PHP code

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html=file_get_html("http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html");
$html=new simple_html_dom($html);

foreach($html->find('table tr') as $row) {
$cell = $row->find('td', 0);
echo $row;
}
?>
```

What I want to get (if you view [the website](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html)) is:
 Club name, played, won, lost, goals for, goals against, goal difference, and points.

What I get is everything in the table, including the collapsed team information. It looks like this (not sure if a picture is the best way to post it but I'm not sure how to show it in another way, I highlighted the part that I actually want scraped):

[image: Picture]

Comment: Are there any specific ids associated with table rows?

Comment: Yeah, but they each have different names, the <tr> classes I want are named: club-row1,2,3,4,5,6 etc. and the <td> classes are named: col-club,col-p,col-d etc. If that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the advanced usage of [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)?

I wrote this based on the manual at the link above; it might get you in the right direction:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$html=file_get_html("http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html");
$html=new simple_html_dom($html);

$rows = array();
foreach($html->find('table.leagueTable tr.club-row') as $tr){
    $row = array();
    foreach($tr->find('td.col-club,td.col-p,td.col-w,td.col-l,td.col-gf,td.col-ga,td.col-gd,td.col-pts') as $td){
        $row[] = $td->innertext;
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
}
var_dump($rows);
```

Essentially, you want all the `<tr>` elements which have a class of `club-row` (adding a `.` indicates class); furthermore, you only want rows which are nested within the `<table>` with class `leagueTable`. That's what the first find is doing. The space after the table indicates you want descendants of it.

Next, you want `<td>` elements which have the various classes you mentioned. You can separate these with a comma to mean "and". (*Give me td.col-club AND td.col-p AND...*)

The `foreach` loops are simply walking through those parsed DOM elements and adding their innertext to an array. You can do whatever you like with them after that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, probably a bit too fresh to simple HTML DOM to understand this code, I'll have a look and try it anyways!

Comment: Just had a look on the edited version, also works great!! thanks a bunch.

Comment: I just tested and updated my answer. Take a look and try it out!

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped out very much.

Comment: just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May be playing a little around this solution may produce the results for you. I have tried for a class and it is fetching the results for one row. Check if it is the solution you are looking for:

```
<?php
    $grab = file_get_contents("http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html");
    $first = explode( '<td class="col-sort">' , $grab );
    $second = explode("</td>" , $first[1] );
?>
<table style="width:80%">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $second["1"];?> (LP)</td>
    <td><?php echo $second["2"];?> (Club)</td>
    <td><?php echo $second["3"];?> (P)</td>
    <td><?php echo $second["4"];?> (W)</td>
    <td><?php echo $second["5"];?> (D)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = array();
foreach($html->find('table',0)->find('tr') as $row) {
$club = $row->find('.col-club', 0);
$p = $row->find('.col-p', 0);
$output[] = array("club" => $club->innertext , "p" => $p->innertext);
}
var_dump($output);
```

This is what i would do

EDIT: the traversing part:

```
foreach($output as $row)
{
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{ 
 echo $key ."|||" . $value ."</br>";
}
echo "</br>";
}
```

EDIT:
Forgot extracting the innertext~

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way I can echo this and see what it looks like?

Comment: the var_dump part will echo everything, right click-show source code on your browser to see the output formated also added how to treverse through the array

Comment: Ok i forgot to actually extract the innertext and just put the entire object on the array, now this should do the trick

Comment: Cheers mate, will have a look!